# "Strange" right representation of Lie Algebras

Tags: symmetry, coordinate-systems, representation-theory, lie-algebra

while reading [Freedman & van Proeyen's book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521194016), I found a very strange claim concerning representation on Lie Algebras: they define a generic transformation spanned by the parameter $ε^A$  and "abstract" element of the algebra $T_A$
$$
δ(ε)=ε^AT_A,\tag{1}
$$
then on fields
$$
T_Aφ^i = -(t_A)^i_jφ^j\tag{2}
$$
where $t_A$ is a matrix. Now they claim that

> ... a symmetry transformation acts on the field, which are dynamical variables of the system, and not of the matrices, which are the result of a prior transformation.

to be more explicit they write:
$$
\begin{align}
δ(ε_1)δ(ε_2)φ^i & = ε_1^AT_Aε_2^B\left[-(t_B)^i_jφ^j \right]\\
& = ε^A_1ε^B_2(-t_B)^i_jT_Aφ^j\\
& = ε^A_1ε^B_2(-t_B)^i_j(-t_A)^j_kφ^k.
\end{align}
$$

That seems a *right* action since the order of matrices $t$ is inverted respect to the abstract element of Lie Algebra $T$, but the matrices are composed as an (ordinary) *left* action! They further comment on that:

> It is important to realize that, in the second line, the transformation operator acts on the field $φ^j$ , and not on the ‘numbers’ $(t_B )^i_j$.

This claim and the whole motivation above seems to me at leas very awkward since to me $(t_A)^i_jφ^j$ (sum on $j$) *is itself a field*. Not just $φ^j$ but also when you multiply it by the matrix $t_A$. This is for me rather obvious since one can define
$$
φ'^i:=(t_A)^j_iφ^j
$$
and so the "field detector" fails. How can $T_A$ know if the field on which it acts has been previously acted on by other $T$s? Indeed when I perform a field transformation I expect to obtain again a field as a result, a field with the same dignity of the first, with the same properties, and therefore that cannot be discriminated from the first one. How can they give a motivation like that? Is it mathematically correct? (I don't think so)

## WAY  OUT

In my opinion the correct definition to have a right action in stead of (1) is
$$
T_Aφ^i=φ^j(-t_A)^i_j
$$
so that (2) becomes
$$
\begin{align}
δ(ε_1)δ(ε_2)φ^i & = ε_1^AT_Aε_2^B\left[φ^j(-t_B)_j^i \right]\\
&= ε_1^Aε_2^Bφ^k(-t_B)_k^j(-t_A)_j^i
\end{align}
$$

The point is that this cannot be a simple type since they motivate their passages with that weird claim above.

What do you think about?

Comment: Review your [passive transformations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_and_passive_transformation). Consider a rotation of a vector, so components dotted on basis vectors. The components are "numbers" in this language. Rotate the basis vectors and behold the right action on the rotation generators. Do you *now see* the significance  of the - sign? Try an obvious example. Compose, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Let us first properly define all objects in play here. Let $\mathfrak{g}$ be the Lie algebra with chosen basis $T_A$ and $V$ the target space of the fields. We have maps
$$ \delta : \mathbb{R}^{\dim(\mathfrak{g})}\to \mathfrak{g},\epsilon\mapsto \epsilon^A T_A$$
and
$$ \rho : \mathfrak{g}\to \mathfrak{gl}(V), T_A\mapsto t_A.$$

$\delta$ is compatible with the Lie bracket in the sense that 
$$ [\delta(\epsilon_1),\delta(\epsilon_2)] = \epsilon^A_1\epsilon^B_2[T_A,T_B]$$ but we may notice that the definition of $\rho$ is incomplete: It is defined on the basis and linearly extended but we don't know how it behaves with respect to the Lie algebra structure. In particular, we don't know whether $\rho([T_A,T_B]) = [t_A,t_B]$ or not. Note that asking what $\rho(T_AT_B)$ is non-sensical because this product is not defined on the level of the abstract Lie algebra itself, so we really have no a priori expectations about what the $\rho(T_A)\rho(T_B)$ should be equal to.

All the rather confusing "arguments" presented in your question essentially amount to *defining* $\rho$ to fulfill $\rho([T_A,T_B]) = [t_B,t_A]$. For an example of such a map, consider the concatenation of a usual representation of a Lie algebra $\sigma$ with $\sigma([T_A,T_B]) = [\sigma(T_A),\sigma(T_B)]$ with the transpose or the adjoint. You are correct that this gives formally a right action of the (enveloping algebra of the) Lie algebra.

As [Cosmas Zachos](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/66086/cosmas-zachos) comments, the true underlying motivation is that your source seems to consider the action of the Lie algebra as a [passive transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_and_passive_transformation), which acts on the *basis* and not on the vectors.

Comment: $\mathfrak{gl}(V)$ is a well-known Lie algebra which does also have an associative product, namely composition. So $\rho$ is perfectly defined and $\rho(T_A) \rho(T_B)$ makes sense. It is then true that $\rho$ may not be a Lie algebra morphism at all if one chooses the $t_a$ arbitrarily. In particular, having $\rho\big( [T_A, T_B]\big)= [t_B, t_A]= \left[-\rho(T_B), -\rho(T_A) \right] = \left[\rho(T_B), \rho(T_A) \right]  $ says that $\rho$ is not a Lie algebra morphism (wrong order), unless the commutation are actually 0.

Answer (score 0):

There is indeed a problem with the definition of your book. As you have already written, if one is given $\varphi'\,^i = (t_A)^i{}_j\, \varphi^j$ without knowing that this field was already obtained from a previous transformation (i.e. without knowing the r.h.s.) then how should it be transformed?

One can check that decomposing $\varphi'$ in different ways will lead to different transformations:
$$\left\lbrace \begin{aligned}
 \text{if}\ \varphi'\,^i = M^i{}_j\, \varphi^j\ \text{then }\ T_A\, \varphi'\, ^i &= - M^i{}_j\,(t_A)^j{}_k\, \varphi^k\\
\text{but if}\ \varphi'\,^i = \varphi^i\ \text{then }\ T_A\, \varphi'\, ^ i &= - (t_A)^i{}_j\, \varphi^j
\end{aligned} \right. $$

Also the authors obviously confuse the transformation of the group and that of the Lie algebra: schematically $\ g = 1 + \epsilon^A \, T_A + o(\epsilon)$ in the group so that 
$$ \begin{equation} 
   \begin{split}
    g_1\cdot g_2 &= (1 + \epsilon_1^A \, T_A) \cdot (1 + \epsilon_2^A \, T_A) + o(\epsilon_1, \epsilon_2)\\
    &= 1 + \epsilon_1^A \, T_A + \epsilon_2^A \, T_A + o(\epsilon_1, \epsilon_2)
   \end{split}
  \end{equation}$$
so that the successive action of the algebra should correspond to adding the actions (vs. composition for the group).

Finally if one tries the "passive" transformation (for a matrix group if one is to calculate) one indeed finds a right action, simply because one takes inverse:
$$g\cdot \varphi = (M_g^{-1})^i{}_j \, \varphi^j$$
where $g$ denotes an element in the group and $M_g$ the associated matrix. Then for the algebra, if $M_g= \mathbb{1} + \epsilon^A\, T_A + o(\epsilon)$ then $M_g^{-1}= \mathbb{1} - \epsilon^A\, T_A + o(\epsilon)$ which explains the minus in $ T_A\, \varphi' = - (t_A)^j{}_k\, \varphi^k$